# How can I automatically shutdown an ECS cluster after a period of inactivity across tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

Is there a way to automatically delete an ECS cluster once all its tasks have been inactive for a certain period of time? If so, how would one go about it e.g. console, cloudwatch alarm, health check monitoring, exit status etc.?

As a postscript, what is a way to communicate inactivity to the proposed watchdog? That is, if all tasks have exited cleanly and therefore, say, failed their health checks, could the cluster be made to shut down?

Thanks as ever

Comment: Are you running ECS services, or individual ECS tasks not connected to ECS services? You mentioned health checks that sound like load balancer health checks, but those would only be for ECS services that run 24/7, not individual ECS tasks. What are these tasks doing exactly? Are they processing data from an SQS queue or something? Are you trying to scale down to 0 EC2 cluster instances to save costs? Or do you really want to delete the cluster for some reason?

Comment: Also, are you deploying your tasks to EC2 or Fargate?

Comment: Thank you! Fargate. In this case no services, just tasks launched via dask. No SQS in this case (too easy :|), so no way to alarm on queue length. They are processing S3 files, so I could alarm on blob count. What do you think? I just want to delete it for housekeeping - no cost of idle AFAIK? Can you believe we are not persisting the clusters...

Comment: The dask client doesn't always exit cleanly, so sometimes the cluster undesirably persists.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Lambda function run occasionally that checks if there are 0 running tasks in the cluster, and deletes the cluster if that is true. If you don't want to run that on a periodic schedule, you could instead have it triggered by an [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-what-is.html) rule that watches for [ECS events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html).

> The dask client doesn't always exit cleanly, so sometimes the cluster undesirably persists

You will need to sort that out so that all your tasks exit properly. I would look into adding a [container health check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) to your task to deal with this.